# How to instruct gmail tabbed view?

Tags: gmail, categories, incoming-mail

In the new Gmail tabbed view, I'm trying to send our company's newsletters but they keep getting filed under `Promotions`, when they should be categorized as `Updates` or `Social` (they are about relevant news of the day, similar to Linkedin Top News newsletter - nothing related to products and/or deals).

Is there any recommendation for instructing gmail on how to categorize incoming emails into the appropriate tabbed view?

I'm open to work on the content and/or template and/or headers.

Answer (score 12):

I have been in correspondence with a product manager at Google about this.

The main hint he gave me is that we should be using a [List-Id header](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2919.txt) in our email notifications.

He said they are working on a reporting mechanism as well, but I'd urge you to follow his advice and implement the List-Id.